# How to generate md5 signatures when uploading python packages to pypi?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi, python-wheel

I am trying to generate and add the md5 hash for new releases that I am uploading on pypi but I wasn't able to find how can I do this.

So far, the only reference I found was this https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html but it does not include any information.

For example, I was able to add PGP signing easily but for md5, it seems that there is no documentation.

My current release command looks like:

```
python setup.py register sdist bdist_wheel upload_docs upload --sign --identity 17D27B8A
```

Comment: PyPI adds MD5 hashes *for you*. Where are you trying to add MD5 hashes yourself?

Comment: @MartijnPieters oops, this seems to be the case. I was confused because on some packages you see the `(md5)` link similar to the `(sig)` one, but on mine it does display as a different column.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add a MD5 hash for PyPI packages. PyPI calculates these *for you*.

That is in fact what the `pip install` documentation [refers to](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#hash-verification):

> PyPI **provides** md5 hashes in the hash fragment of package download urls.

(emphasis mine).

All you need to do is upload your package (binary or source) to your PyPI project and PyPI will take it from there.

Comment: Thanks! That was really quick. If you also know a way to force the overwrite of an existing release (or to remove it) from the command line, it would be great.

Comment: @sorin: IIRC just re-upload the release. **Be very careful** however. Don't re-use release numbers if you made a code mistake. Make a new release instead; if people already downloaded and installed the faulty release they'll have a hard time uninstalling and re-installing and most of the time won't even notice that you re-released the package.

Comment: @sorin: in any case, you cannot *remove* releases with the `setuptools` command line utilities; use the PyPI web interface for that.